# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when performing a closure

Tags: swift3

I want to perform a closure after delay time, but a runtime error occurred. I know GCD can do this easier, but I want to know why.

thanks.

Here is my code:

```
func perform(_ aClosure:@escaping ()->Void, afterDelay delay: TimeInterval) {
    self.perform(#selector(fire(closure:)), with: aClosure, afterDelay: delay)
}

func fire(closure:()->Void) {
    closure() // error
}

self.perform({ 
     print("closure do something... ...")
}, afterDelay: 2)
```

Comment: I think it's because selector doesn't expect Swift closure as an object. It's type mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like everybody (including you ;>) says, use GCD. If, for whatever reasons, you insist on using `perform(_:with:afterDelay:)`, try changing the type of the `closure` parameter to `Any`:

```
func fire(closure: Any)
{
    (closure as! ()->Void)()
}
```

See [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44279) for more information. Also, from [section "id Compatibility"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID42) in "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 3.0.1)":

> The Objective-C id type is imported by Swift as the Any type. At
>   compile time and runtime, the compiler introduces a universal bridging
>   conversion operation when a Swift value or object is passed into
>   Objective-C as an id parameter. When id values are imported into Swift
>   as Any, the runtime automatically handles bridging back to either
>   class references or Swift value types.

And `NSObject`'s `perform(_:​with:​after​Delay:​)` [API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-performselector):

> **a​Selector**
>   A Selector that identifies the method to invoke. The method
>   should not have a significant return value and should take a single
>   argument of type id, or no arguments.

Comment: It's a exact answer. Thank you.